# Intel Fortran Corrupts DLL

Tags: dll, fortran, intel

I am building a dll with Intel Fortran via VS 2015. The output is a dll file with one subroutine (which I am sure is exported because I checked dll with depends tool). But when I try to use in in C priject, VC++ says that it cant read dll and file is corrupted (error LINK1107).

The fortran-side code is

```
subroutine ADD(x,y,z)
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, DECORATE, ALIAS : 'ADD' :: ADD
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: x
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: y
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: z

    integer x, y, z

    z = x + y
end subroutine
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the .dll file in the C project - instead use the import library (.lib) that was generated when the dll was built.